# Rails getting error using radio button tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, radio-button

I am using devise authentication for my application.So i am trying to use radio button tag but i am getting error **undefined method `permit' for "status":String**  in **NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create**.At sign up page  i was just adding a radio button tag but was getting that error.

[views/devise/registration/new.html.erb]

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %> <% if @validatable %><i>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</i><% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %></div>


  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %></div>
    <br/>

    <div >

      <%= f.label "user" %>
      <%= radio_button_tag 'user','status' %>


      </div>


  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

[user.rb]

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments

  validates :status,presence:true

  def self.find_role(id)
    User.find(id).roles
  end   

end
```

**And also I have a status column in my users table**

[stacktrace]

```
devise (3.3.0) lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb:66:in `permit'
devise (3.3.0) lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb:54:in `sign_up'
devise (3.3.0) lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb:77:in `default_sanitize'
devise (3.3.0) lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb:24:in `sanitize'
devise (3.3.0) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:142:in `sign_up_params'
devise (3.3.0) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:17:in `create'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:45:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/home/techbirds/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/techbirds/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/techbirds/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

[console]

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-11 10:31:24 +0530
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"SQ+xVq0Pf4a+b038sIEOcxhVaDWs5wqujrmEjYxATEs=", "user"=>"status", "commit"=>"Sign up"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms
NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for "status":String):
  devise (3.3.0) lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb:66:in `permit'
  devise (3.3.0) lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb:54:in `sign_up'
  devise (3.3.0) lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb:77:in `default_sanitize'
  devise (3.3.0) lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb:24:in `sanitize'
  devise (3.3.0) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:142:in `sign_up_params'
  devise (3.3.0) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:17:in `create'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:45:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /home/techbirds/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/techbirds/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/techbirds/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /home/techbirds/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered /home/techbirds/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /home/techbirds/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /home/techbirds/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (15.6ms)
```

Comment: Can you give us the full stacktrace?

Comment: updated my answer with stacktrace also with console screen

Comment: The `status` field will raise an error unless you change the devise controller. Why do you pass this value, what's the use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that `radio_button_tag` is overriding all parameters passed to the devise controller. Try `<%= radio_button_tag 'user[status]','1' %>` in your view instead of what you've now. You've to adjust the `status` type. Here I just assume it's a string.

Comment: status is a column in my users table and its datatype is boolean

Answer (score 1):

Also, radio_button_tag should just be f.radio_button. The tag is not necessary.

And make sure config/initializers/devise.rb has 'config.scoped_views = true' to allow you to edit devise forms.